# Dotenv multiline variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, shell

I'm using [`dotenv`](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv).

> A Ruby gem to load environment variables from `.env`.

Is it possible to have multiline variables in my `.env` file?

e.g.

```
SOMETHING_CERTIFICATE="-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
JSDFALDAFSSKLABVCXZLV2314IH4IHDFG9AYDF9DSSDF82QWEIWFHDSSD8SADF0=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
```

^ having the above just throws an error on that middle line, as if it's not part of the string and I'm trying to create an improperly formatted variable.

Comment: Did you tried "\n"?

Comment: I did try "\n", it just came up in the error message automatically parsed to "\\n"—but that's because I tried to keep the whitespace newlines as well as the "\n"s. Putting it all on a single line with the "\n" worked, although it's not really what i wanted, it gets ugly for long strings.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv#multi-line-values)

> Multi-line values
>
> If you need multiline variables, for example private keys, you can double quote strings and use the \n character for newlines:
>
> PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nHkVN9…\n-----END DSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"

Comment: To add to Brian answer. If you need to consume the PRIVATE_KEY in a config file for example, you can do something like this:

```signing_key "<<-EOL\n" + "#{ENV['PRIVATE_KEY']}".gsub("\\n","\n") + "EOL\n"```

Comment: Answers containing “Did you try reading the documentation” do not deserve upvotes.

Comment: `sed` version for the lazy: `cat id_rsa | sed -z -e 's/\n/\\n/g'`

Comment: With the changes in dotenv 3.0.0 (https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv/releases/tag/v3.0.0) this pattern no longer works. See SaturnFromTitan's answer for the 3.0+ syntax.

Answer (score 48):

From the documentation Brian posted above:

> Alternatively, multi-line values with line breaks are now supported for quoted values.

So the solution you sketched in your question is legit now!

Comment: Weirdly, in a docker setup, me and my colleague (same OS) are getting inconsistencies with that. I Think it might be safest to add the newlines.

Comment: Fine for dotenv, I don't know for other scenarios https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv#multi-line-values . 

Answer (score 0):

If you are using node, you could use `fixedKey = key.replaceAll('\\n', '\n')`

And in the .env
`KEY=-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- xY=\n.....3ZaWjyKJqy+xY=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n`

Fix the error `replaceAll is not a function` changing the lib option under compilerOptions in the tsconfig.json for "es2021" if you are using typeScript.